# Как работает сравнение массивов?

Tags: javascript, массивы

```js
let arr1 = [[1, 2, 3][(4, 5, 6)]];
let arr2 = [...arr1];
console.log(arr1[0] === arr2[0]); //true

arr1[0] = [7, 8, 9];
console.log(arr1[0] === arr2[0]); //false почему???
```

```js
let arr1 = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]];
let arr2 = [...arr1];
console.log(arr1[0] === arr2[0]); //true
```

Comment: `console.log(arr1, arr2)` пробовали в разных местах кода? Видели, что за значения принимают переменные, иначе в чем вопрос? JS удивительный язык тем, что молча проглатывает `[[1, 2, 3][(4, 5, 6)]]`, даже не представляю, чего хотелось этим добиться.

Answer (score 11):

`let arr1 = [[1, 2, 3][(4, 5, 6)]];`

Круглые скобки превращают свои внутренности в выражение (expression)

Использован [оператор - запятая](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F). Там, где ожидается одно значение, он позволяет вычислить несколько выражений, а вернуть только значение последнего. Поэтому:

`[[1, 2, 3][(4, 5, 6)]]` → `[[1, 2, 3][6]]`

`[1, 2, 3][6]` → Из массива `[1, 2, 3]` достается `[6]`-й элемент (его нет): `undefined`. В итогде в `arr1` попадает массив с одним элементом `[undefined]`

`let arr2 = [...arr1];` — элементы первого массива передаются во второй массив, `arr2` теперь тоже `[undefined]`

`console.log(arr1[0] === arr2[0]); // undefined === undefined → true;`

---

А тут:

```
arr1[0] = [7, 8, 9];

console.log(arr1[0] === arr2[0]); // [7, 8, 9] === undefined → false;
```

---

Чаще используйте console.log()...

```js
let arr1 = [[1, 2, 3][(4, 5, 6)]];
console.log(arr1); // [undefined]

let arr2 = [...arr1];
console.log(arr2); // [undefined]

console.log(arr1[0], arr2[0], arr1[0] === arr2[0]); // undefined undefined true

arr1[0] = [7, 8, 9];
console.log(arr1[0], arr2[0], arr1[0] === arr2[0]); // [7,8,9] undefined false

/***/

const fn = () => (true, 100500, "Запятая!");

console.log( fn() ); // "Запятая!"
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100vh; }
.as-console-wrapper code { white-space: nowrap; }
```

---

---

По второй части:

```js
let arr1 = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]];
let arr2 = [...arr1];

console.log( arr1 ); // [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ] ]
console.log( arr2 ); // [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ] ]

console.log(arr1[0], arr2[0], arr1[0] === arr2[0]); // [ 1, 2, 3 ] [ 1, 2, 3 ] true
console.log( [ 1, 2, 3 ] === [ 1, 2, 3 ] ) // false
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100vh; }
.as-console-wrapper code { white-space: nowrap; }
```

В чем подвох? `console.log( [ 1, 2, 3 ] === [ 1, 2, 3 ] )` при вызове console.log здесь создается два разных объекта. Через строгое сравнение, массив никогда не будет равен никакому другому массиву. Они могут хранить одинаковые данные, но являются разными объектами.

В переменных, свойствах: Создаваемый массиив не хранится "физически". В переменную попадает ссылка на этот массив.

А при передаче элементов `let arr2 = [...arr1];` копируются именно ссылки, указывающие на эти массивы. Заново не создаются новые массивы. Т.е. `arr1[0]` и `arr2[0]` — это **ссылка** на один и тот же массив `[1, 2, 3]`, которая может одновременно храниться в разных местах.

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = arr1;

console.log( arr1 === arr2 ); // true;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr1 = [[1, 2, 3][(4, 5, 6)]];
```

вот этот треш `[1, 2, 3][(4, 5, 6)]` javascript воспринимает как `undefined`

в результате

```
let arr1 = [undefined]
```

т.е. массив с 1 элементом, который неопределён

```
arr2 = [...arr1];
```

копирует массив `arr1` в `arr2`

В этот момент массивы равны, а затем вы меняете массив `arr1`, записывая в качестве первого элемента массив `[7, 8, 9]` и массивы `[[7, 8, 9]]` и `[undefined]` уже не равны :)

Но вот Javascript какой-то странный язык, который почему-то выводит позднее значение в виде раннего (именно выводит, а не присваивает):

```
let arr1 = [[1, 2, 3][(4, 5, 6)]];
let arr2 = [...arr1]; 
console.log(arr1); // выведется [undefined]
console.log(arr1[10] === arr2[0]);
console.log(arr1[0] === arr2[0]);
```

но

```
let arr1 = [[1, 2, 3][(4, 5, 6)]];
let arr2 = [...arr1]; 
console.log(arr1); // выведется [7, 8, 9]

arr1[0] = [7, 8, 9];
console.log(arr1[0] === arr2[0]);
console.log(arr1[0] === arr2[0]);
```

Comment: Это не JS странный, это консоль браузера так устроена.

Comment: @Yaant, о том и речь - не правильно выразился просто :) поскольку работа кода никак не изменяется, а вот вывод...